# How to fix lag between images in Fotorama?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a series of images in my image slider from Fotorama. My problem is that
there is a very slight delay when transitioning between different slides for the first time, I imagine because my images are all quite large. Is there any way to easily fix this through javascript or html/css? I read their documentation regarding 'lazy loading' but I'm not sure if that is really applicable for what I want to do. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
    <div class="fotorama"
    data-margin="0"
    data-transition="slide"
    transition-duration="0ms"
    data-keyboard="true"
    data-swipe="true"
    data-click="false"
    data-width="100%"
    data-height="95%"
    data-ratio="3/2">

    <img src="images/bgardenflower2.jpg">
    <img src="images/yellowflower.jpg">
    <img src="images/lushflower.jpg">
    <img src="images/flowerbee.jpg">
    <img src="images/fly.jpg">
    <img src="images/bgardenflower1.jpg">
    <img src="images/toad.jpg">
    <img src="images/algae.jpg">
    <img src="images/lushscape1.jpg">
    <img src="images/westvirginia1.jpg">
    <img src="images/westvirginia2.jpg">
    <img src="images/duskbridge.jpg">
    <img src="images/lighthouse.jpg">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using photoshop you can save images in webformat, so the images size will be reduced and load quickly...